# spaces are not printing when reads the input file

Tags: c++

I am trying to read each 'char' of the input file and write in the output file until finds the '?' as the end of file . Every char  is written in output file except the spaces between words. I dont know what's wrong in this code??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   ifstream infile("in.txt");
   ofstream outfile("out.txt");
   char ch;
   infile >> ch;
   while(ch != '?')
   {
     outfile<<ch;
     infile >> ch;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [noskipws](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noskipws/) on read...

```
infile >> noskipws >> ch;
```

The noskipws tells the input stream to not skip whitespace which it does by default.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew it works. I have a question => the deafault beahvior of  reading a file is "to skip the spaces" if any ??

Comment: @Alok: don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the green check and giving a good upvote :)

Comment: @Alok: anyway, from looking at your profile I bet you know what you're doing; good luck with your projects

Answer (score 1):

istream operator `>>` ignores whitespace.  Try this:

```
std::string s;
std::getline(infile,s,'?');
outfile << s;
```

Comment: Or tell it not to by using noskipws (see answer). Though, getline is probably going to be faster.

Comment: @Andrew: Oh yeah, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

The >> operator for input streams is generally associated with interpretation. For example, when reading `string`s it skips spaces. This may be the case when reading `char`s.
You ought to use the `read` method, for example:

```
infile.read(&ch, 1)
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/ for reference

**edit** I forgot about the `get` method. That'll get you a single character, cast as an `int`. The `read` method is more geared for reading a chunk of data in one call.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew White has already pointed out how to fix the problem you've seen. I'll toss in my idea (typically for me, probably over-engineered) idea of how to do the rest of the job:

```
#pragma once
#if !defined(SENTINEL_ITERATOR_H_)
#define  SENTINEL_ITERATOR_H_
#include <istream>
#include <iterator>

template <class T,
          class charT=char,
          class traits=std::char_traits<charT>,
          class distance = ptrdiff_t>

class sentinel_iterator :
    public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag,distance,void,void,void>
{
    std::basic_istream<charT,traits> *is;
    T value;
public:
    typedef charT char_type;
    typedef traits traits_type;
    typedef std::basic_istream<charT,traits> istream_type;

    sentinel_iterator(istream_type& s)
        : is(&s)
    { s >> value; }

    sentinel_iterator(T const &s) : is(0), value(s) { }

    const T &operator*() const { return value;  }
    const T *operator->() const { return &value; }

    sentinel_iterator &operator++() {
        (*is)>>value;
        return *this;
    }

    sentinel_iterator &operator++(int) {
        sentinel_iterator tmp = *this;
        (*is)>>value;
        return (tmp);
    }

    bool operator==(sentinel_iterator<T,charT,traits,distance> const &x) {
        return value == x.value;
    }

    bool operator!=(sentinel_iterator<T,charT,traits,distance> const &x) {
        return !(value == x.value);
    }
};

#endif
```

Then the code becomes something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include "sentinel_iterator.h"

int main() { 
    ifstream infile("in.txt");
    ofstream outfile("out.txt");

    infile >> noskipws;

    std::copy(sentinel_iterator<char>(infile),
              sentinel_iterator<char>('?'),
              std::ostream_iterator<char>(outfile));
    return 0;
}
```