# Getting Multiline Input for parsing in C++

Tags: c++, cin

I want to create a program which allows the user to type multi-line input into the console, and then when they press a certain key, in this case it would be the key `F`, input will stop and everything is stored into the `string` called `input`.

This string should have all the input the user entered, including white spaces, new lines, etc. I want it to be a string that can be parsed later on in the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

 string input;
 while(cin >> input){

    // Code for exiting the loop when the key "K" is pressed should be put here.

 }


}
```

Comment: so what is your __question__?

Comment: Apart from declaring what you *want*, can you also show what you have *tried*?

Comment: It seems like the `sentinel_iterator` I posted in a [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6657066/179910) should work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string input;
string line;

while (getline(cin, line))
{
    if (line == "K\n")
        break;

    input += line;
}
```

Comment: [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/). The newline is discarded.

Comment: Is there any way to delete the newline char and go back up to the previous line?